# Is it possible to extend my Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-extensions, zimbabwean-citizens

I am a Zimbabwean on holiday in UK on a 6 month family visitor. I got a 30-day Schengen visa so I can visit Europe as well. I just want to find out if it is possible to extend the Schengen holiday visa from UK or Europe without having to go back to Zimbabwe first?

Comment: It is probably not possible. But using this visa correctly (i.e. not overstaying) will work in your favour when applying for future Schengen visas.

Answer (score 6):

Extensions are limited to very specific circumstances and even applying for another separate visa is typically not possible without being a resident in the country where you apply. So the answer is almost certainly **no, it's not possible**.